# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - Activity Crash

Tags: java, android

When loading an activity my app is instantly crashing with an "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" logcat.

The application crashes as soon as this activity tries to run.

My activity code is:

```
package com.example.cg4project;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChildScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child_screen);



    //Gte child array size
    int arraySize = Global.getInstance().childArray.size();

    if (arraySize == 0){

    }else{//Create new button
        Button myButton = new Button(this);

        //For loop from 0 to array size
        for(int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++){
            //Set button text
            myButton.setText(Global.getInstance().childArray.get(counter).aFirstName + " " + Global.getInstance().childArray.get(counter).aLastName + " Stars: " + Global.getInstance().childArray.get(counter).aPoints);
            //Create linear layout
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //Add button to layout
            ll.addView(myButton, lp);

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Open child activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(ChildScreen.this, Child.class);
                    ChildScreen.this.startActivity(i);

                }
            });

        }
    }





    final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Open child create activity
            Intent i = new Intent(ChildScreen.this, ChildCreate.class);
            ChildScreen.this.startActivity(i);
        }

        });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.child_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And my logcat is.

```
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458): Process: com.example.cg4project, PID: 3458
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cg4project/com.example.cg4project.ChildScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at com.example.cg4project.ChildScreen.onCreate(ChildScreen.java:64)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-09 10:07:24.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3458):     ... 11 more
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/userAccounts.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at com.example.cg4project.Login.onCreate(Login.java:29)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-09 10:12:24.816: W/System.err(3789):     ... 16 more
02-09 10:12:24.896: D/libEGL(3789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
02-09 10:12:24.916: D/libEGL(3789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
02-09 10:12:24.946: D/libEGL(3789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
02-09 10:12:24.966: D/OpenGLRenderer(3789): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: The stacktrace says it all mate.. you have one "File Not Found Exception" and a "Nul Pointer Exception"..

Comment: The file not found isn't even for this activity though. On this activity there is no mention of that file.

Comment: And therefore, the `NullPointerException` is the cause of the crash. What's on line 64 in ChildScreen.java that might be `null`?

Comment: btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {